# How to send emails without intents and without using external providers that have daily limits?

Tags: android

One way to send email is using intent which will ask mail sending apps to do the action. Another way is to use smtp of external providers like gmail but they normally have daily limits as described in the following link.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

Here is a usage scenario. I want to email user a thank you email after a user signsup or creates an account. It wouldn't be feasible to just use gmail or yahoo smtp because the limits are very strict per day. So, i am wondering is there an option to send email in background without daily limits and also without the use of intents via a mail sending app?

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a service dedicated to sending emails like MailChimp. They have an API. It looks like they have a free tier and paid tiers. I'm sure there are other similar providers as well.